# Api does not have register attribute. flask_restplus

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, python-3.8

Создаю небольшое Апи на фласке. При помощи `flask_restplus` пытаюсь создать `Namespace` для одного из контроллеров в приложении:

```py
# controllers/catalog_controller.py

from flask_restplus import Namespace, Resource

catalog_namespace = Namespace('catalogs', description='Catalogs CRUD')

@catalog_namespace.route('/')
class CatalogResource(Resource):
...
```

После чего создаю Api, как показано в документации [тут](https://flask-restplus.readthedocs.io/en/stable/scaling.html#use-with-blueprints):

```py
# controllers/__init__.py

from flask import Blueprint
from flask_restplus import Api

from controllers.catalog_controller import catalog_namespace

api_bp = Blueprint('Terminology API', __name__, url_prefix='api/')
api = Api(api_bp, title='My Title', version='1.0', description='A description',)

api.add_namespace(catalog_namespace)
```

Эти два этапа отрабатывают без ошибок. Проблема в следующем:

```py
# app.py

from flask import Flask

from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()

from controllers import api


app = Flask(__name__)

app.register_blueprint(api)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

На строчке `app.register_blueprint(api)` выскакивает ошибка:

```
AttributeError: Api does not have register attribute
```

Уже не первые сутки бьюсь с этой проблемой. В интернете почти ничего нет. На руках есть проект с точно такой же реализацией и там все работает как часы. 
Прошу помощи.

Comment: Лучше перенести информацию о решении проблемы из вопроса в ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался. Я пытался зарегистрировать `api`, которая не является блюпринтом. Нужно было в `app.py` прописывать `app.register_blueprint(api_bp)`